# Editing config file via a bash script on ubuntu

Tags: scripting

i am trying to write a script that will edit a config file on ubuntu

i need to enable an option for ip forward
for the file /etc/sysctl.conf

i need to edit this line, from this

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

to that:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

to remove the "#"

can i do it with a script?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/^#\(net.ipv4.ip_forward.*\)/\1/' /etc/sysctl.conf`. Try it without the `-i` first to see if it works as expected.

Comment: Please be aware that your code requirement does not match your written requirement. The code as shown will enable the setting that _disables_ forwarding for IPv4. I think you also meant to change the line to `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Stream EDitor `sed` to do this.

```bash
sudo sed -i '/net\.ipv4\.ip_forward =/s/^#//' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This command runs using `sudo`, which is needed to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`. `sudo` calls `sed -i` which edits the files instead of printing the result to stdout. `/net\.ipv4\.ip_forward =/` is a regex that looks for lines to modify, and `s/^#//` removes `#` only if it is the first character of the line.

One good practice when finding the right syntax for your edits is to *not* use `sed -i` and instead just use `sed` and view what comes out.

Also, if you want another safety net, you can run `sed -i.bak` which will create a backup file with `.bak` as the suffix. Be careful where you use that though, because the backup is created in the same dir as the original file, which can cause issues in various circumstances, such as when all the files in a directory are read, such as various `.d` directories.